# Debug assertion error with memory allocation

Tags: c, debugging, memory, assertion

im getting a "debug assertion error" when this code compiles, with the expression _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block), can anyone explain why this has happened, and how to resolve

```
typedef struct _POOL
{
    int size;
    void* memory;

} Pool;

Pool * allocatePool(int n)
{

    int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

    Pool pool = { sizeof(*p), *p };

    return &pool;

}

void freePool(Pool* pool)
{
    free(pool);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 errors in your approach:

1. You return a pointer to a variable with automatic storage.
2. You call `free()` on a pointer that doesn't point to dynamic memory.

What this means is you should also allocate the space for your `Pool` object dynamically. In your `freePool` you must then free both the memory pointed to by `void *memory` and the `Pool *` itself.

```
Pool *allocatePool(int n)
{
    Pool *pool = malloc(sizeof *pool);

    if (!pool) {
        /* malloc failed, bail out */
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Caller is responsible for passing non negative value as n.
       Negative values will have suprising effects. */
    int *p = malloc(sizeof *p * n);

    /* Failed malloc, or n was 0 and current implementation returns
       NULL. */
    if (!p) {
        /* Clean up already allocated memory */
        free(pool);
        /* Many dislike multiple return points in a function, but
           I think for this little example it's ok. That, or gotos. */
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Storing the size of single item seems dubious. Size of the whole
       allocated area in objects is much more useful. */
    pool->size = n;
    pool->memory = p;
    return pool;    
}
```

and

```
void freePool(Pool *pool)
{
    free(pool->memory);
    free(pool);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

```
Pool * allocatePool(int n)
{
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    Pool *pool = malloc(sizeof(Pool));
    pool->memory = p;
    pool->size = n;
    return pool;
}
```

BTW: the casts of `malloc` are not necessary.

Comment: @David they necessary are in C++ but not in C. See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 0):

These two functions

```
Pool * allocatePool(int n)
{

    int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

    Pool pool = { sizeof(*p), *p };

    return &pool;

}

void freePool(Pool* pool)
{
    free(pool);
}
```

does not make sense.

For example the first function returns pointer to a local object of type `Pool` that will not alive after exiting the function. Moreover this initialization is invalid

```
Pool pool = { sizeof(*p), *p };
```

I think you meant at least the following

```
Pool pool = { n, p };
```

or maybe

```
Pool pool = { n * sizeof( int ), p };
```

The functions can look the following way

```
Pool allocatePool( int n )
{
    Pool pool = { 0, NULL };
    void *p;

    if ( n > 0 && ( p = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) ) ) != NULL )
    {
        pool.size = n;
        pool.memory = p;
    }

    return pool;
}

void freePool( Pool *pool )
{
    free( pool->memory );
    pool->size = 0;
    pool->memory = NULL;
}
```